# Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient thrown even though axis jar was there

Tags: java, web-services, axis, noclassdeffounderror, nexus

I am writing a plugin for nexus oss . where I am using axis for making webservice calls . It throws an

**InvocationTargetException : target : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient**

so i was apprehensive if nexus could not find my axis jar as it threw this NoClassDefFoundError. so I started debugging step by step  to check if nexus knows my axis jar and while debugging I found that the the control goes inside the axis jar (so my assumption that nexus did not see axis jar is wrong ). It went inside [Service.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis/axis/1.4/org/apache/axis/client/Service.java#103) in axis and there the code was like

```
protected AxisClient getAxisClient() {
    return new AxisClient(getEngineConfiguration());
}

/**
 * Constructs a new Service object - this assumes the caller will set
 * the appropriate fields by hand rather than getting them from the
 * WSDL.
 */
public Service() {
    engine = getAxisClient();
}
```

It was throwing this exception at line engine = getAxisClient(); that is actually at line return new AxisClient(getEngineConfiguration()); inside getAxisClient method . 
so if it can find service.java which is inside axis.jar , there cannot be any reason why it cannot find the AxisClient class which is in the same package in axis jar.

So can you please help me in spotting out the reasons for this exception.

Is my axis jar not fetched by nexus ? 
How to find if the jar was fetched by nexus ?

Comment: You should add your stacktrace

Comment: I would suggest to use the nexus client library rather that exposes the REST API of Nexus in Java classes already rather than writing your own with Axis. It also provides a bunch of other helpful classes to do things like Nexus version checks and so on.

Comment: I am not reinventing a rest api . I am using their rest plugin only . During authentication(custom authentication) with my server I do a soap call because my server responds to soap login only.This soap call is within the authtentication module.

Comment: Fait enough - from your question that was not clear.

Comment: May be ,sorry , if question frustrated you. May be my language is the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My boss helped me find the answer .

It was actually the problem with commons-logging . I loaded a commons-logging in my nexus .The nexus which was running in a jetty server itself had a commons-logging , so there was a conflict . Now I removed my commons logging from the plugin descriptor . Then the problem was over , my plugin started working .

Thanks .

Comment: I added "commons-discovery" as well.

Comment: This was my case. If you are using any other Apache Libraries which come with a compiled dependency of Apache Commons-logging this night be the case. 

  `compile("org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:1.4"){
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }`